# Owner draw controls Windows Phone-Windows Store app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I started developing a Windows 8 (Metro style)-Windows Phone 8 application that will have (between the other things) a multilayer image editor. The problem is that this thing would be pretty easy with owner draw controls...but i can't find anything like that :O

I searched everywhere, but there is not something like the OnPaint/OnDraw/OnRender/OnXXXX or things like that! Am i missing something?

Thanks to everybody!

*Side Note:*

For my use case I founded a workaround, a Canvas with a WritableBitmap, this way I can have a "raster" surface instead of the list of items. Other than this I use the [WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) that wraps the WritableBitmap with all the various APIs like DrawLine, Ellipse, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right there is **no OnPaint/OnDraw/OnRender** in Windows Phone App.

If you want to keep it strictly XAML the best thing you can do is make your custom control
from the Canvas object like this.

```xaml
<Canvas x:Name="my_canvas">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="200" />
    <!-- more ui elements -->
</Canvas>
```

You can programmatically add in items using C# by doing this (it can get really tedious if you're drawing a lot of objects... like say drawing a fine stock chart)

```C#
this.my_canvas.Children.Add(my_ui_element);
```

---

There is also Windows Phone XNA which I used for a game I have uploaded to the store.  In there you will have to deal with a gaming loop and content pipeline which is not easy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the case as well.  It reminds me of those silly .innerHTML solutions.